# Assign a column with := named with a character object while performing an operation by group

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using R's data table, and am trying to assign a column with := named with a character object while performing an operation by group.

If it's not done by group, things are [relatively straightforward](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#assign-a-column-with--named-with-a-character-object):

```
dt <- data.table(mtcars)[, .(cyl, mpg)]

thing2 <- 'mpgx2'
dt[,(thing2):=mpg*2]
```

However, when I'm doing things by group, an error occurs:

```
DT <- data.table(V1=c(1L,2L),
                 V2=LETTERS[1:3],
                 V3=round(rnorm(4),4),
                 V4=1:12)

ghi <- "def"

DT[,.((ghi)=mean(V3)),by=V1]
```

Specifically, `Error: unexpected '=' in "DT[,.((ghi)="`.

How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
DT[,setNames(.(mean(V3)), ghi), by = V1]
#   V1     def
#1:  1 -1.4663
#2:  2  0.0414
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Just a note to future readers that setNames should not be confused with setnames, the latter being a data.table function.